# Postman: sending nested JSON object

Tags: json, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am using ASP.NET Web API: http://xyzdomain.com:16845/api/returns/returns

How do I send a POST request to the endpoint using Postman Chrome extension, given `Items` is a collection:

```
[
  {
    "Items": [
      {
        "sku": "9257",
        "Price": "100",
        "Quantity": "500",
        "DiscountPercent": "1",
        "backordered": "2"
      }
    ],
    "order_id": "F429768865001",
    "status_code": "Shelf",
    "Exception": "no error"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 194):

Send it as raw data and set the type to `application/json`

[image]

Comment: what is actually happening when this data is sent as raw? Where and how is it stored in the request?

Comment: I'd use a web proxy to look at that if your curious (for example: fiddler on Windows, charles proxy on mac)

Comment: How Do I add an image file in the raw JSON request?

Comment: Yeah how do we add/upload image with raw JSON request. @Shikharvarshney Did you find a better way ?

Comment: A life saver ... Thank you!! Working with Ruby on Rails, the prior code had nested ActionController::Parameters, within parent ActionController::Parameters. It took me a few hours, to figure out, that in Postman, it's: Body > Raw > JSON, not JSON within the Params.

Answer (score 168):

To post a nested object with the key-value interface you can use a similar method to sending arrays.
Pass an object key in square brackets after the object index.

[image: Passing a nested item with Postman]

```
"Items": [
      {
        "sku": "9257",
        "Price": "100"
      }
 ]
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my humble opinion... The easiest and most managable.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, just that I had to write Items[sku] instead of Items[0][sku]

Comment: In my case, I had a nested object called location with city, state and country in it. I had to write location.city, location.state, etc.

Comment: Does this still work ? I do not think it does, Postman ends up making the entire "Items[0][SKU]" as a string

Answer (score 35):

This is a combination of the above, because I had to read several posts to understand.

1. In the **Headers**, add the following key-values:

   1. `Content-Type` to `application/json`
   2. and `Accept` to `application/json`

[image]

2. In the **Body**:

   1. change the type to "raw"
   2. confirm "JSON (application/json)" is the text type
   3. put the nested property there: `{ "Obj1" : { "key1" : "val1" } }`

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It should be `application/json`, not `applications`

Comment: @TBirkulosis : With your approach, Json will not be sent with Header

Answer (score 33):

I got it working using the Raw data option in postman, as you can see in the screen shot

[image]

Comment: where exactly is this handling the nested data scenario? that's just the non-nested data which is being sent

Answer (score 26):

The key-value pair can take advanced inputs.

Ex.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton man, I figured this would be there but I was trying dot annotation. This is certainly the correct answer

Answer (score 23):

Simply add these parameters :
In the **header** option of the request, add `Content-Type:application/json`

[image: header content-type postman json]

and in the **body**, select **Raw** format and put your json params like `{'guid':'61791957-81A3-4264-8F32-49BCFB4544D8'}`

[image: json request postman]

I've found the solution on http://www.iminfo.in/post/post-json-postman-rest-client-chrome

Answer (score 17):

Select the *body* tab and select *application/json* in the Content-Type drop-down and add a body like this:

```
{
  "Username":"ABC",
  "Password":"ABC"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Just wanted to add one more problem that some people might find on top of all the other answers. Sending JSON object using RAW data and setting the type to `application/json` is what is to be done as has been mentioned above.

Even though I had done so, I got error in the POSTMAN request, it was because I accidentally forgot to create a default constructor for both child class.

Say if I had to send a JSON of format:

```
{
 "firstname" : "John",
 "lastname" : "Doe",
 "book":{
   "name":"Some Book",
   "price":12.2
  }
}
```

Then just make sure you create a default constructor for Book class.

I know this is a simple and uncommon error, but did certainly help me.

Answer (score 6):

Best way to do that:

1. In the Headers, add the following key-values:

   ```
   Content-Type to applications/json
   Accept to applications/json
   ```
2. Under body, click `raw` and dropdown type to `application/json`

**Also PFA for the same**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For a nested Json(example below), you can form a query using postman as shown below.

```
{
    "Items": {
        "sku": "10 Units",
        "Price": "20 Rs"
    },
    "Characteristics": {
        "color": "blue",
        "weight": "2 lb"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for those who want to send a nested JSON object with form-data as content type.

I want to send nested custom_field in below 
`{ "description": "Details about the issue...", "subject": "Support Needed...", "type": "Others", "email": "tom@outerspace.com", "priority": 1, "status": 2, **"custom_fields" : { "cf_type_of_issue" : "Complaint" }**, "cc_emails": ["ram@freshdesk.com","diana@freshdesk.com"] }`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Params I have added model.Email and model.Password, work for me well. Thanks for the question. I tried the same thing in headers did not work. But it worked on Body with form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded.

Postman version 6.4.4

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can send nested JSON like the following format

```
address[city]
address[state]
```

Comment: You seem to have confused JSON with extended application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it as key-value Query Param via GET, you can paste your json in the inputtext as value, and then select this text, right click on it and click *"EncodeUriComponent"*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post single nested dictionary lets say:

**Wrong:**

```
{

 parent_key: { child_key: child_value }

}
```

You need to convert it to:

**Correct**

```
{

 parent_key.child_key: child_value

}
```

And if you wanted to post list of dictionaries lets say:

**Wrong:**

```
{

 parent_key: [

    { child_key: child_value },
    { child_key: child_value_02 }
  ]

}
```

You need to convert it to:

**Correct**

```
{

 parent_key[0]child_key: child_value
 parent_key[1]child_key: child_value_02

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Postman `form-data`, add nested obj or arr of nested objs in `JSON.stringify` format to the value field.

```
KEY = Items    VALUE = "{"sku": 9257, "Price":"100"}"
```

Then `JSON.parse` on the back end.