# Json object sent by postman received with null members

Tags: java, json, postman

This is a follow up question to this question:

[sending nested json object using postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705782/sending-nested-json-object-using-postman)

I am trying to send a Json object to a Jersey web service using Postman.

I am doing it like this:

On the Jersey side:

```
@Path("/testMethod")
@POST
@UnitOfWork
public short testMethod(@NotNull @BeanParam Test test)
{ ... }
```

Test class is a simple class:

```
public class Test
{
    public String field;

    public Test()
    {

    }
}
```

On the postman side I'm sending a POST message with Body set as raw and the content type is set as Json(application/json). The body itself is:

```
{
 "field" : "12"
}
```

When sending this request, the `field` in the received parameter is null... why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to map your json data to object, then just remove `@BeanParam` and it will work properly.

However, if you want to use `@BeanParam` feature, you should remove that annotation from first parameter, and add second parameter annotated with `@BeanParam`:

```
@Path("/testMethod")
@POST
@UnitOfWork
public short testMethod(@NotNull Test test, @BeanParam ExtraTest extraTest)
{ ... }
```

and then implement your ExtraTest class with additional fields mappings:

```
public class ExtraTest
{
    @HeaderParam("Accept")
    public String acceptHeader;

    /* 
    your other header params, path params and so on...
    ...
    */
}
```

`@BeanParam` is the feature that allows you to easily access additional request information (header fields, query params etc.). It couldn't be mixed with your json data object mapping.

More information:

https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/new-in-jax-rs-2-0-beanparam-annotation/

https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html

Comment: When should I accept a Json object without the BeanParam annotation and when should I use it?

Comment: Check my edited answer. `@BeanParam` is a mechanism that allows you to easy access additional request information (headers, query params etc.).