# Why won't my rest api post request save my array in my mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I'm trying to learn to make an api with node.js For my backend i'm using mongodb and I'm using mongoose as ORM. I created my user model as follows.

```
// User.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var UserInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    street: String,
    housenumber: String,
    city: String,
    postcode: String,
    bus: String,
  });
var UserFullSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  Userinfo: [UserInfoSchema]
});


mongoose.model('User', UserFullSchema);

const User = mongoose.model('user',UserFullSchema)
module.exports = User;
```

My Usercontroller looks like this:

```
// UserController.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var User = require('./User');
// CREATES A NEW USER




router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    User.create({
        name : req.body.name,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password,
        Userinfo: [{
            street : req.body.street,
            housenumber : req.housenumber,
            city : req.body.city,
            postcode : req.body.postcode,
            bus : req.body.bus,
        }]
    }, 
        function (err, user) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            res.status(200).send(user);
        });
});
```

For some reason when I call my API using postman to test I can never seen to be able populate my array. Did I do something wrong?

Picture as example:
[image]

Page I checked before posting:
[Page I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705782/sending-nested-json-object-using-postman/32495988)

Answer (score 0):

You definition where you want to have a cross reference by the `_id` seems off.

```
Userinfo: [UserInfoSchema]
```

should probably be:

```
Userinfo: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:  'UserInfoSchema' }]
```

This way you would have a cross reference by `_id`. Btw not a fan of those names. It reads very confusing. I assume these are just for testing.

Comment: Changing Userinfo didn't work. Now im getting the message "There was a problem adding the information to the database." in postman. And yes the names are only for testing.

Comment: That was the first step. Next one is to review your `.create` and change it since you cannot add like this. You would have to first create the model for `UserInfoSchema` then add its _id as part of the `User.create` `UserInfo`. You are sending with your post an _id and somehow that is getting into values? IT does not work this way. Read this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

Now, from a simple `express` kinda perspective Are you even referencing the values from req.body?
Shouldn't the values be `req.body.Userinfo.street`?

```
Userinfo: [{
        street : req.body.Userinfo.street, // 
        housenumber : req.body.Userinfo.housenumber,
        city : req.body.Userinfo.city,
        postcode : req.body.Userinfo.postcode,
        bus : req.body.Userinfo.bus,
    }]
```

On a side note, you can send Full fledged JSON using postman, go to the `raw` tab and select `application/json` from the dropdown

Comment: Tried changing as you suggested but still the same result. I also tried sending via JSON but when I did no variables were populated not even the User variables.

Comment: can you console log the req.body and check if everything is coming as expected or not?

Comment: body:
   { name: 'Pedro Lopes',
     email: 'pedro@hotmail.com',
     password: '789852123',
     Userinfo: { street: 'street' } },
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  read: [Function],
  route: Route { path: '/', stack: [ [Object] ], methods: { post: true } } }

Comment: So the problem is not in the postman request it is somehow how Im saving users to the database

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the problem was but I was able to resolve the issue by splitting my models in 2 different files.
I made a new file called Userinfo like this:

```
// Userinfo.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var UserInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    street: String,
    housenumber: String,
    city: String,
    postcode: String,
    bus: String,
  });

module.exports = UserInfoSchema;
```

There I exported my whole Schema

And called that Schema in my User model file like this:

```
// User.js

var Userinfo = require('../userinfo/Userinfo.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var UserFullSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  Userinfo: [Userinfo]
});

const User = mongoose.model('user',UserFullSchema)
module.exports = User;
```

And my controller looked like this:

```
// UserController.js
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var User = require('./User');


router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    User.create({
        name : req.body.name,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password,
        Userinfo: [{
            street : req.body.Userinfo.street,
            housenumber : req.body.Userinfo.housenumber,
            city : req.body.Userinfo.city,
            postcode : req.body.Userinfo.postcode,
            bus : req.body.Userinfo.bus,
        }]
    }, 
        function (err, user) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            res.status(200).send(user);
            console.log(req);
        });
});
```

After that I used postman as before and voila issue resolved:
[image: Postman]