# Why postman POST method do not provide params in `json` format?

Tags: flask, postman

In my flask project, there is a route:

```
def request_parse(req_data):
    if req_data.method == 'POST':
        data = req_data.json
    elif req_data.method == 'GET':
        data = req_data.args
    return data

@app.route('/api/d/u', methods=['POST'])
def update():  # name, domain_list, pem_key, pem_cert, origin_ips

    data = request_parse(request)
    name = data.get('name')
    domain_list = data.get('domain_list')
    pem_key = data.get('pem_key')
    pem_cert = data.get('pem_cert')
    origin_ips = data.get('origin_ips')
```

in Postman I request it like this:

[image]

I use postman request the api:

you see it is POST method, and in my project debug, I found the request data is in `form`,not in `json`.

[image]

I also tried `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` format, all are in `form`.

why postman POST method do not provide params to `request.json`? and is it possible to provide params in `request.json`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman: sending nested JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705782/postman-sending-nested-json-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send it as JSON, change from  `x-www-form-urlencoded` to `raw` and you should see a drop down for `Text, JSON, HTML`. You can then select `JSON`